# Trigger on Object when lookup field is modified

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, before-trigger

I have a custom  Object MyObject__c which has one field Contact__c lookup on Contact object and trigger on it. I want trigger to update ContactName field of MyObject__c when ever Contact object is deleted.I could see that LastModifiedDate of MyObject__c is getting updated on Contact record delete but trigger is not fired.

```
trigger ContactNameUpdate on MyObject__c (before insert,before update) {
    List<MyObject__c> stObjects = Trigger.new;
    system.debug('Inside trigger '+JSON.serialize(stObjects));
    for(MyObject__c st : stObjects){
            st.ContactName__c = st.Contact__r.Name;
        }
}
```

What I am missing in above code? Please leave comment if problem is not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of, no need to cast the trigger.new

Second, the Relationship Name will ALWAYS be null in the trigger context.

**3rd, Simply use a formula field to get the name no need for a trigger**

But in case you do not wish to use a formula field (not sure why you would not but...) here is code to do what you want

```
trigger ContactNameUpdate on MyObject__c (before insert,before update) {
  Map<ID,String> recToName = New Map<ID,Name>();

  for(MyObject__c mo : trigger.new){
      if(mo.Contact__c != null)
        recToName.put(mo.Contact__c,null);
  }

  for(Contact c : [Select Name From Contact Where ID IN :recToName.keySet()]){
      recToName.put(c.id,c.Name);
  }

    for(MyObject__c st : trigger.new){
            //st.ContactName__c = st.Contact__r.Name; //Contact__r.Name will always be null unless you query for it
         st.ContactName__c = st.Contact__c == null ? null : recToName.get(st.Contact__c);
        }
}
```

Comment: st.ContactName__c = st.Contact__c == null ? null : recToName.get(st.Contact__c); will always assign null.

Comment: @San - How do you figure? If Contact__c is null it assigns null, if it is not, it get the Map value for the key

Comment: But you put null in map recToName.put(mo.Contact__c,null); even if it is not null.

Comment: @San - Follow the code - Look at the second for loop. The first loop just populates the IDs to use in the query

Comment: @San - Why are you even bothering with the code anyway. Just use a formula field. Why would you not be able to do that?

Comment: How to Update ContactName when contact is being deleted? because contact object won't be available. 
Let me give a try by using formula field.
Sorry my bad i did not see second line of code.

Comment: If the contact is removed from the object then the value will be set to null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25085/discussion-between-san-and-eric).